# Abort fetching data in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component Preloader. It shows when I make API calls. Also this component has button "Cancel" and I want to abort all my API calls when I press this button. How can I make it?

I make requests to API using redux-effects-fetch.

Comment: Please list your code and also mention any approaches you tried.

Comment: Please take some time and read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`redux-effects-fetch` uses [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch), that implements whatwg-compatible Fetch API.

Request aborting now [is not supported](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/27) yet.

So, if you need to cancel pending request, you need to consider switching to another library. For example [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) is also isomorphic request library and has `.abort()`.